# AWK negative regular expression

Tags: awk, regular-expression

I am looking to have a awk regular expression that can give all strings not matching a particular word.

using   `/^((?!word \+).)*/`  works in java but does not work in AWK.

Get compilation failed error,   escaping the brackets fixes the compilation error, but the regular expression matching is not correct.

It would be great if any one can help with a awk regular expression .

I can not use  `string" !~ /regex/`

I need to use `string" ~ /regex/`   regex shuould pass for all string but for a specific string.

Strings containing `domain` should be filtered out. 
Input

```
This is domain test
This is do test
This is test
```

Output

```
This is do test
This is test
```

Need to do with regular expression only. Can not change the Awk code

in AWK its like `string" ~ /regex/`

so can only pass a regex to achieve this.

Comment: if you add sample input and expected output, perhaps there might be a workaround... or use `perl`

Comment: "I can not use "string" !~ /regex/"   Why not?  What is the actual problem being solved?

Comment: The awk code is fixed.  I can only pass regular expression to ignore few strings

Comment: In the future, you should give a copy-paste ready code sample with a variable for the only bit you are able to change. Most people aren't going to glean clues about an X-Y problem from comments you sprinkle on multiple answers.

Answer (score 43):

While Thomas Dickey's answer is clever, there is a right way to do this:

```
awk '!/domain/ {print}' <<EOF
This is domain test
This is do test
This is test
EOF

This is do test
This is test
```

Comment: The OP said they can't use `string !~ /regex/`

Comment: The OP said they tried to use a `!` in a way that didn't work. This demonstrates the correct way to use it. I don't see what your issue is.

Comment: Sounds like OP is looking for schoolwork help. No other reason not to use `!~` or `!/.../`.

Comment: @IsaacFreeman, they *might* be dealing with a code-generating-code situation where the nested quoting is resulting in [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#History-Interaction). Or they might have just been suffering from misuse of the `!` caused them to believe it *couldn't work*. Either way, at this point, it's for posterity and not for the OP.

Comment: interesting just `!` didn't work. `git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --summary HEAD | awk -F' ' 'OFS=" " { if ( $1 !/delete/ ) { print $1, $4 } }' ` output nothing for me, but this output my creates `git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --summary HEAD | awk -F' ' 'OFS=" " { if ( $1 !~ /delete/ ) { print $1, $4 } }'`

Comment: @xenoterracide I did my `!` in the `pattern` portion of a `pattern{action}` statement. You did yours in the `expression` portion of a `if (expression) statement`. Your use requires an `operator` to indicate "intention to do match", aka: a `matchop` of `~` or `!~`. You could have also done `{ if($1 ~ !/delete/){...} }` but you could NOT have done it without the `if()` because you used `OFS=" "` **incorrectly**. You use it as a `pattern` instead of an `expression`. Lucky for you, it always returns `true`. I prefer https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=awk because it is briefer than GNU doc

Answer (score 20):

The way you do this in awk is to write a pattern that matches what you want to *exclude*, and make its *action* **`next`**.  That leaves the lines to process which are the negation of the pattern which you are trying to achieve.

Something like this:

```
/regex/{ next; }
{ print; }
```

Or if your script is more complicated and you can't use `next`:

```
<<<'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'$'\n''pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs' awk '
{ negate=0 }
/box/{ negate=1 }
negate==1 { gsub(/[aeiou]/, "%") }
negate==0 { gsub(/[aeiou]/, "#") }
{ print NR, $0; }
'

# output
1 th# q##ck br#wn f#x j#mps #v#r th# l#zy d#g
2 p%ck my b%x w%th f%v% d%z%n l%q%%r j%gs
```

Comment: you can put a `!` in front of the `/regex/` to negate it. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/465862/9745

Comment: This is so useful for more complex logic. 

Answer (score 8):

> Because you stated **"Need to do with regular expression only. Can not
>   change the Awk code"** try this:

**Instead of "negation of the operator" you can "negate the regex"**. You just need to pass **negation symbol `!`** as part of regex `!/domain/` to awk script.

```bsh
awk '{if ($0 ~ !/domain/) {print $0}}'
```

Answer (score 4):

`awk` does not support PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expression), so you can not use any zero width lookarounds like the negative lookahead you are using, `(?!word +)`.

`awk`'s Regex engine only supports ERE (Extended Regular Expression). You need to incorporate all logics in there or you can break up the logic to meet your need. Also look at the builtin functions of `awk`, check  if they are of any help in the regard.

Comment: Thanks! Now I know why it does not work.  I can not change the logic, as the awk code is fixed(out of control), I can only change the regex.

Answer (score 4):

Writing a negated pattern with POSIX extended regular expressions is particularly tricky. For this case of a string like `domain` where all the characters are different, you can try:

```
awk -v re="^([^d]|d*d[^do]|[do]*o(d*d[^do]|[^dm])|[dom]*m(d*d[^do]|[do]\
*o(d*d[^do]|[^dm])|[^da])|[doma]*a(d*d[^do]|[do]*o(d*d[^do]|[^dm])|[dom\
]*m(d*d[^do]|[do]*o(d*d[^do]|[^dm])|[^da])|[^di])|[domai]*i(d*d[^do]|[d\
o]*o(d*d[^do]|[^dm])|[dom]*m(d*d[^do]|[do]*o(d*d[^do]|[^dm])|[^da])|[do\
ma]*a(d*d[^do]|[do]*o(d*d[^do]|[^dm])|[dom]*m(d*d[^do]|[do]*o(d*d[^do]|\
[^dm])|[^da])|[^di])|[^dn]))*[domai]*\$" '$0 ~ re'
```

I did come up with that years ago and come back to [that article of mine](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.unix.shell/c/dMA7D9wLe6E/m/wFmWk234hWYJ) whenever I need to write a negative regexp, but I must admit I don't remember how I got to that.

Comment: I wonder how I got two downvotes but no comment proving me it's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Tried with below 3 methods

**First method** using `awk`

- command

  ```shell
  awk '$0 !~/domain/{print $0}' file.txt
  ```

  resulting output

  ```
  This is do test
  This is test
  ```

**Second method** using `sed`

- command

  ```shell
  sed -n '/domain/!p' file.txt
  ```
- resulting output:

  ```
  This is do test
  This is test
  ```

**Third method** using `python`

- python script

  ```python
  #!/usr/bin/python
  k=open('test.txt','r')
  for i in k:
      if "domain" not in i:
          print i.strip()
  ```
- resulting output

  ```
  This is do test
  This is test
  ```

Comment: Re: your awk solution, for whatever reason, the OP said: `I can not use  string" !~ /regex/`

Comment: I'm upvoting, because this is ranked high on google for negating a row in awk, and unlike any of the other answers this actually worked for me. side comment, the second output isn't actually quoted