# Inverse regex in AWK?

Tags: awk, regular-expression

I am trying to filter out the lines containing a particular word. The regex is command line input to the script.

```
$0 ~ regex {
//Do something.
}
```

Sample input is:

```
**String** **number**
domain  1
domain  2
bla     3
```

So, from the above input, user can say - filter out the rows which have word "domain".

**What I've tried:**

```
regex = "\?\\!domain"
```

(negative lookahead).

But this regex is filtering out every row. Not just the rows with word "domain".

Comment: Seems `awk -v p="domain" '$0 !~ p'` should work ... ?

Comment: just few minutes back this was posted - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318839/awk-negative-regular-expression awk doesn't support lookarounds...

Comment: @Sundeep, missed that post..my requirement is exactly same

Comment: but why do you need lookaround for the question described? if you need to print lines containing `domain`, use `awk '/domain/{print}'`.. if you do not want lines containing `domain`, use `awk '!/domain/{print}'`

Answer (score 18):

For given input file `input` containing the following:

```
domain
demesne
```

To filter for lines containing `domain`:

```
$ awk '/domain/ { print }' input
domain
```

To filter for lines *not* containing `domain`:

```
$ awk '!/domain/ {print }' input
demesne
```

For filtering based on the *field* rather than the entire line, we can try the following for the new given `input` file:

```
example www.example.com
exemplar www.example.net
```

To filter out lines where the first field *contains* `example`:

```
$ awk '$1 !~ /example/ { print }' input
exemplar www.example.net
```

In your question, you used `$0` which is the entire line rather than the first field.

Answer (score 3):

Another more flexible/powerful way to filter out lines is with `{next}`:

- In order to print all lines that **do not** match a given `regex`, do:

  ```
  awk '/regex/ {next} {print}' inputfile
  ```

You can even filter out all lines between two specific lines with this method, as follows:

- To print all lines that **are not** between a line matching `regex1` and the first next line matching `regex2`, do:

  ```
  awk '/regex1/,/regex2/ {next} {print}' inputfile
  ```

  which isn't possible with the `awk '!/regex/'` method (if I'm not mistaken).

For instance, if your `inputfile`'s content is this:

```
hello, here is my confidential information

SECRET INFO BEGIN
xx
x
xxxxx
xxxx
xxxx
xxxxx
xs
sdf
sdfsdfw
wefwe
SECRET INFO END

This is the end of my message
```

Then, this command `awk '/SECRET INFO BEGIN/,/SECRET INFO END/ {next} {print}' inputfile` would print:

```
hello, here is my confidential information


This is the end of my message
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'hello, here is my confidential information

SECRET INFO BEGIN
xx
x
xxxxx
xxxx
xxxx
xxxxx
xs
sdf
sdfsdfw
wefwe
SECRET INFO END

This is the end of my message' |
```

---

```
 mawk 'BEGIN { _^= FS = RS } ! /SECRET INFO/ ? _ : _ * (_=!_)'

 gawk 'BEGIN { _^= FS = "SECRET INFO" } _*(NF <= _^_ || _=!_)'
```

---

```
hello, here is my confidential information


This is the end of my message
```