# awk replace if text matches regex. If not replace with something else. Is this possible with awk?

Tags: awk

For a file containing records such as:

```
ABC|YE0000123543|BLAH|XYZ|24.12.2025|J
ABC|YE0000123544|BLAH|MNO|24.12.2025|K
```

If the fourth field contains XYZ, replace it with a Y. If not, replace it with N.

Sounds simple, right?
Well apparently *not* matching something with awk is extremely difficult, if not impossible, or I'm just not getting it.

**Substitute for a match**:

```
$ echo "ABC|YE0000123543|BLAH|XYZ|24.12.2025|J"|awk -F '|' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } {gsub(/XYZ/, "Y", $4);} {print $0}'
ABC|YE0000123543|BLAH|Y|24.12.2025|J
```

**So far so good! Now to print N for a non-match:**

Just negate the regex, right? **!/XYZ/**

```
$ echo "ABC|YE0000123543|BLAH|MNO|24.12.2025|J"|awk -F '|' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } {gsub(!/XYZ/, "N", $4);} {print $0}'
ABC|YE0000123543|BLAH|MNO|24.12.2025|J
```

No? It just doesn't work.

Looking at [other answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318839/awk-negative-regular-expression) on SO leaves me none the wiser. Nothing seems to be able to reliably substitute for a non-matching regex in awk.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: ITYM `If the fourth field is XYZ` rather than `If the fourth field contains XYZ`. Regarding `apparently not matching something with awk is extremely difficult,` - using any tool it's almost always trivial to match whatever you want but much harder to not match similar text you don't want.

Comment: Regarding `Just negate the regex, right? !/XYZ/` - no, there is no negation of regexps (in BREs or EREs anyway, idk about PCREs). You can negate a condition that's testing a regexp but that's not negating the regexp. You can negate a bracket expression within a regexp, e.g. `[!a]` would match any character that isn't `a` but again that's not negating a whole regexp. `sub(/XYZ/` means "replace `XYZ`", but `sub(!/XYZ/` means "replace 0  if `XYZ` exists in $0 or 1 otherwise".

Comment: To "negate a regexp" like `XYZ` you'd first have to figure out what that means. Given input like `abcXYZ`, obviously `XYZ` DOES match `XYZ` but what's the negation of that? Is it `abc`? Or is is `a`, and `b`, and `c` individually? Does it include the null strings between each character? Does it match `XY` and `YZ` and `bcX`, etc.? There's no obvious answer.  What you probably had in mind when expressed as a regexp would be written as `sub(/^([^X]|.[^Y]|..[^Z]|.{4,})$/` but it's not exactly elegant and it's not as simple as just negating the original regexp using some negation operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cat change script like:

```
$ awk -F '|' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } {if("XYZ"==$4) $4="Y" ;else $4="N"; print }' input_file >output_file
```

Answer (score 4):

As @Romeo also suggested, string equality can be more accurate than a regex.

I'd write

```bash
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"} {$4 = ($4 == "XYZ" ? "Y" : "N")} 1' file
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks very much man. So obvious it's embarassing.

Answer (score 0):

There are umpteen ways to skin a cat... You seem to want to replace the entire field 4, no? Try a "conditional" operator:

```
awk -F '|' '{$4=($4=="XYZ")?"Y":"N"} 1' OFS="|" file5
ABC|YE0000123543|BLAH|Y|24.12.2025|J
ABC|YE0000123544|BLAH|N|24.12.2025|K
```

Comment: Sorry but @glennjackman beat you to it (posted the exact same answer, somewhat earlier). And it is a community answer (if you want to contribute).

Answer (score 0):

Your original code contains a bare regular expression, which is matched against the whole line. That may cause unintended matches.

If you really need a pattern match (not just a text equality), the syntax to match a field with a pattern is like:

```
$4 ~ /myRegExp/
```

That can be negated with an operator like:

```
$4 !~ /myRegExp/
```

The sub() function returns the number of substitutions, so you can force alternatives like:

```
if (! sub (/myRegExp/, "Text_A", $4)) $4 = "myDefault";
```

For free-format text (rather than fields with FS), the `match()` function can be very helpful. It returns built-in variables `RSTART` and `RLENGTH`, which permit you to use `substr()` to reference the matched text, rather than the field notation like `$4`.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'my @a = .split("|"); @a.[3] eq "XYZ" ?? (@a.[3] = "Y") !! (@a.[3] = "N"); @a.join("|").put;'  file
```

OR

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'my @a = .split("|"); @a.[3] = (@a.[3] eq "XYZ" ?? "Y" !! "N"); @a.join("|").put;'  file
```

Does it have to be `awk`? Here's a solution using Raku's ternary operator: "(Condition) `??` True `!!` False". The nice thing about the `split`/`join` approach above is it sets you up if you want to join on commas, to make a simple-`csv` file. Otherwise, the Raku reads similar to the `awk` answers posted, noting that Raku (and Perl5) are zero-indexed.

https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#index-entry-operator_ternary
https://raku.org